# TCP Client socket hanging the Server Socket

Tags: java, android, sockets

I am developing an TCP/IP socket program to connect my Android phone with my server PC.

I have created a simple echo program.

After connecting to server I can send my registration command without any problem/delay/hanging.

After I receive using my buffered reader I pass the data to my function in main activity which interns sends this data to server by writing to OutputStream. While my client sending this data, my server hangs (busy-wait -> my guess) but after 5 seconds it resumes normal operation and receives data successfully. Even my worker thread (AsyncTask) hangs which is evident as their is a noticeable delay to display message in Logcat compared to other messages.

Android Studio 3.3.1

Target API Level : >= 26 (8.0 Oreo)

TCP Test Server - Hercules

```
@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
public void connect(){
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>(){

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
                socket  = new Socket(ip, portNo);
                out     = socket.getOutputStream();
                in      = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                socketAlive.set(true);
                return true;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            if(result){
                sendData("RegisterDevice:<ip>:<mac>");
                readerThread();
            }
            else{
                socketAlive.set(false);
                reconnect();
            }
        }
    }.execute();
}
@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
public void sendData(final String data){
    if(this.socket == null || this.socket.isClosed() )
    {
        //Unable to send data as output is closed returning
        return;
    }
    new AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean>(){
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... writeString) {
            try {
```

> out.write(writeString[0].getBytes()); // -->> Casuing Server Socket to
>   hang

```
                //out.flush();
                return true;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            if(!result) {
                reconnect();
                sendData(data);
            }
        }
    }.execute(data);
}

@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
public void readerThread(){
    if(this.socket.isClosed())
    {
        //Unable to recieve data as output is closed returning
        return;
    }
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>(){
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
                Arrays.fill(readBuffer, '\0');
                //in.read(readBuffer, 0, Ethernet.TCP_READ_BUFFER_SIZE);//8192
                in.read(readBuffer);
                return  true;

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            if(result) {
                //dataRead = String.copyValueOf(readBuffer, 0, Ethernet.TCP_READ_BUFFER_SIZE);
                String str = String.copyValueOf(readBuffer);
                str.trim();
                Log.i("Test", "Test");
                mainActivity.processEthernetData(String.copyValueOf(readBuffer, 0, Ethernet.TCP_READ_BUFFER_SIZE));
                Log.i("ReadInfo", String.copyValueOf(readBuffer, 0, Ethernet.TCP_READ_BUFFER_SIZE));
                readerThread();
            }
            else {
                reconnect();
            }
        }
    }.execute();
}

public void processEthernetData(final String protcol){

    eth.sendData(protcol);
}
```

Comment: The only thing that can hang a `ServerSocket` is its `accept()` method, and that can only happen in the *absence* of client sockets and connections. Your code is mostly rubbish, relying on non-existent properties of `isClosed()` and friends, ignoring the value returned by `read()`, performing pointless array initialisations, &c.

Comment: So why is server hanging along with the thread that is performing out.write and then the server resumes operation after 5 seconds, even successfully receiving and displaying the data that had been transmitted???

Comment: Use tcpdump or Wireshark to diagnose. Why is the `flush()` call commented?

Comment: Flush was used when I tried transmitting with BufferedWriter but with OutputStringStream it was not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by

`mainActivity.processEthernetData(String.copyValueOf(readBuffer, 0, Ethernet.TCP_READ_BUFFER_SIZE));`

Apparently the string created and passed to function was in order of `TCP_READ_BUFFER_SIZE` which of the value 8192. When such a large string was transmitted over TCP/IP it caused my server to hang temporarily till it received complete data.

I resolved the bug by changing the line to

```
mainActivity.processEthernetData(String.copyValueOf(readBuffer, 0, ethernetBytesRead));
```